# Statistica VB - Including an external macro

Tags: statistica

I'm using Statistica 64 VB. I wrote a function "Public MyFunction()" in FileLibrary.svb (a collection of useful functions) that I want to be called by a function in FileDoStuff.svb (an analysis).

I tried to include FileLibrary.svb like this in FileDoStuff.svb:
'#Language "WWB-COM"
'#Uses "U:\TestSVB\FileLibrary.svb"

This is the result when I run Main() in FileDoStuff, and the result is the same even if I have FileLibrary open in the application.
  "Script error in FileDoStuff.svb
   Macro/module does not exist."

Statistica is on the E: drive. However, FileLibrary opens a spreadsheet on U: and has no problem with it. I am able to open FileLibrary from Statistica and test it.

Why would it work to open an external spreadsheet but not call an external macro? The FileLibrary is not saved within Statistica, but neither is the analysis in FileDoStuff. What am I doing wrong?

Also, what's the difference between an SVB and an SVX file?

Comment: You should not tag this [vb.net] unless you are actually using vb.net (for example in Visual Studio). I suspect that what you are using is either VBA or some other VB-like implementation.

Comment: I tagged it VB and the system automatically changed it to VB-net. I tried to tag it Statistica, VB, SVB.

Comment: If you want to ask more questions about Statistica, I suggest you find out what the automation language is. Stack overflow does not have a [vb] tag. If you are not using Visual Studio, then you are not using [vb.net]. As I said, it may be that Statistica implements [vba].

Comment: SVB is compatible with Microsoft's VB.NET, Microsoft's Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), and also with Microsoft's Visual Basic 6.0 (VB6). SVB scripting language is unique in terms of its flexibility and compatibility, and it is also very powerful. It provides access to Visual Basic for Applications (used for scripting Microsoft Office products) and access to the .NET Framework within the same file.  [Macro (Statistica Visual Basic) Overview](http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=Macros/Macro/UnderstandingMacros/VBAOverview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what really helps, as I discovered after hours of trying everything?
Try spelling the **entire** path name and the **entire** file name correctly, including spaces, etc. And make sure the slashes go the right way, too. (In my real path/file there are spaces.)

As much as I'd like to delete this whole question, I'm leaving it here to remind us all that sometimes the answer is just that simple. Also, I want to draw more people out who are using Statistica VB because I know there will be more questions.